# Unable to parse JSON using AS3 and Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I am attempting to parse some JSON from a URL via Flash/AS3. 
Here's my code so far:

```
import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;
import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSONDecoder;

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
request.contentType = "application/json";
request.url="http://shaktiwarriors.guinness.trillitech.com/json/quiz/getNotAnsweredQuestions.php";
//request.url="demo.txt";
loader.load(request);

loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loadConfirm);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,decodeJSON);

function loadConfirm(e:Event):void {
    trace("Load Successful" + "\n");
}

function decodeJSON(event:Event):void {
    var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
    trace(loader.data.toString() + "\n");
    var ids:Array= JSON.decode(loader.data);
    for (var i:int = 0; i < ids.length; ++i){
        trace(ids[i].id);
        my_txt.text = ids[i].id + "\n"
    }
}
```

The trace(loader.data.toString() + "\n") outputs a bunch of HTML. I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @taskinoor - when authenticated the JSON looks like this:[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5},{"id":6},{"id":7},{"id":8},{"id":9},{"id":10},{"id":11},{"id":12},{"id":13},{"id":14},{"id":15},{"id":16},{"id":17},{"id":18}]

Comment: Also, when I copy the JSON into a txt file and then run the code on that txt file it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried the [URL](http://shaktiwarriors.guinness.trillitech.com/json/quiz/getNotAnsweredQuestions.php) in browser it is saying that I need to login which is clearly a HTML, not a JSON. Before trying to parse JSON make sure that you loaded the correct thing. Looks like that you need to authenticate to load the JSON.

Comment: Are you sure that you are loading json correctly in the script? There is no authentication in the code that you have posted.

Comment: Are you doing any authentication in AS3 code? Without authentication, how the loader will load the JSON?

Comment: Thanks, you got me on the right track. The problem was that I was running the code in flash and not in the browser, so it wasn't being authenticated. Thanks again for your help!